# Create function flows in Unity/C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having a bunch of functions that I want happening in a specific order after eachother. Some of the functions are IEnumerators which needs to be finished before next function starts. This would be a representation of what I want:

```
private void MainFunction()
{
    StartCoroutine(FunctionA());
    FunctionB();  // Function A must completely finished before running this
{
```

However, this starts function A first and then as soon as function A returns a null/WaitForSeconds etc function B will start before function A has completed.

One way I found is to just put function B at the end of function A. This however creates a nest of functions (since I in my real code have 5-6 functions I want running after eachother in MainFunction) which makes the code very hard to follow after a few steps:

```
private void MainFunction()
{
    StartCoroutine(FunctionA());
{

private IEnumerator FunctionA()
{
    // Do stuff here
    yield return null;

    FunctionB();
{
```

Is there a way to create this more nicely which would also be more easy to follow? Preferably some trick to get the first code snippet I posted to work?

Comment: Use Tasks and await StartCoroutine or use an AutoResetEvent.

Comment: or use callbacks and pass in what should happen once `FunctionA` is done ... or wrap them all in a bigger IEnumerator and simply `yield return FunctionA();`

Comment: @PalleDue, I have not tried using the things you mentioned before but will google around on them. If you have some short code on how it would work in MainFunction in my quesiton I would appreciate if you could put as an answer and I will accept it

Comment: @PalleDue [`StartCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) is not async so you can't await it ;) It is a Unity thing which actually still runs "synchronously" in the main thread but only gets called `MoveNext` once a frame ... depends of course on what exactly happens inside these so I guess there isn't really a general valid answer to this without having more information but in general going asyncronous in Unity has its pitfalls since most of the API may only be used on the main thread so you always need to dispatch things back there

Comment: Why the negative vote now??

Comment: @derHugo: Sorry, just exposed my lack of unity knowledge there ;-) Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably many approaches for this and all have their pros and cons.

I'd say probably the easiest one would be to simply wrap this into a "mother" routine and do e.g.

```
public void MainMethod()
{
    StartCoroutine(MainMethodRoutine());
}

private IEnumerator MainMethodRoutine()
{
    yield return FunctionA();

    FunctionB();

    ...
}
```

---

Or as said you could use callbacks and rather do e.g.

```
public void MainMethod()
{
    StartCoroutine(FunctionA(() =>
    {
        FunctionB();

        ...
    }));
}

private IEnumerator FunctionA(Action whenDone = null)
{
    ...

    whenDone?.Invoke();
}
```

In my opinion this however already gets a little bit more ugly and harder to read and debug.

Comment: I made MainFunction into a coroutine and then made it first yield return StartCoroutine(FunctionA()) and then put function B after that. It is basically what you wrote so I am accepthing this :)

Comment: @eligolf the `StartCoroutine` for `FunctionA` is actually even redundant except you are ever going to use `StopCoroutine(FunctionA())` ;)

Comment: Great, will remove that then!